# Firebase Google Authentication two steps

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am currently developing a mobile app and I am pretty stuck at the login process with google auth and firebase. Basically, I want a two steps authentication.

1. Google Sign in, then switch to the second intent
2. Let user to change the displayed name and then register user in firebase.

I saw this implementation in Uber Mobile App login flow and I was wondering how I can get the same approach.

Comment: i dont think uber login flow is different than any other app that uses google login.

Comment: Actually if you choose google login you will be prompt with an intent where you'll have to select your google account. After the details are retrieved, they are completed in a form where you have first name, last name and email. You can change those details and then submit. If you do not submit there and reopen the app, you are still not logged and you have to take the login flow again.

Comment: "You can change those details and then submit" these details are from google. once you get the result, you can use the data to create one more step so the user can edit the info if he wants. you are only editing the data before submitting to uber, so uber can create account with the edited details. Google login flow is not different

Comment: I agree. The google login flow is the same. Adding a new activity for detail confirmation makes the login flow different. What I need to do, is to move the 4th step from "https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin" to another activity where I can edit, let's say, the displayed name.